# scipy.optimize problem with matrix constraints

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have an optimization problem as following: 
Minimize:
    the sum '(load[i]-6*X[i])^2, i=1,..N' where load is a known.
constrains: 
    X[i]= {-1 or 0 or 1}
and
    Y[i+1]-Y[i]=1.25x[i]
where 
    Y[1]= Constant1
    Y[N]= Constant2

To start, I am trying to solve it for the following numbers:

p.s: I have tried Gurobi or MIP, but no success

```
n=10
load = [2,.5,1,1.5,1,1.45,2.25,2.45,2.36,1,1.4]
Y[1]=50
Y[11]=58.75
```

My question: If solving this problem is possible with scipy.optimization? Any thoughts are welcome. Thanks.

Edit:

I came up with following Gurobi code:

```
from gurobipy import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
n=11
# Create a new model
m = Model()
# Create variables
x = m.addVars(n,lb=-1,ub=1,vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="x")
Y = m.addVars(n,lb=50,ub=59,vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="Y")
load = [2,.5,1,1.5,1,1.45,2.25,2.45,2.36,1,1.4]
#Y[0]=50
#Y[10]=59

# Add constraint: SOC[start]=50
m.addConstr(Y[0]==50,name='c1')
m.addConstr(Y[n-1]==58.75,name='c2')
m.addConstrs((Y[i+1]-Y[i] == 1.25*x[i] for i in range(n-1)), name='c0')

m.update()

#Y = m.addVar(lb=50,ub=59,vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="Y")
#m.addConstr (Y[0]==50)
# Set objective  
#obj1=quicksum(((load[i]-float(6*x[i]))*(load[i]-float(6*x[i])) for i in 
range (n)))
obj1=quicksum(((load[i]-(6*x[i]))*(load[i]-(6*x[i])) for i in range (n)))
#obj1=quicksum((load[i]-float(6*x[i]) for i in range (n))

m.setObjective(obj1,GRB.MINIMIZE)



m.optimize()
# display solution
m.printAttr('x')
```

Comment: There's no function inside scipy.optimize that can solve MIPs. But it's easy with gurobi. What have you tried so far with gurobi?

Comment: You could also try this rather new library: [MIP](https://pypi.org/project/mip/).

Comment: Thanks @joni. I have to say I am new to this field and don't have much experience. I tried following code, but couldn't go forward!

Comment: from gurobipy import *
     import numpy as np
     import pandas as pd
     m = Model("mip1")
     x = m.addVar(lb=-1,ub=1,vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="x")
     n=11
     load = [2,.5,1,1.5,1,1.45,2.25,2.45,2.36,1,1.4]
     Y[1]=50
     Y[10]=59
     for i in range(n):
           x = m.addVar(lb=-1,ub=1,vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="x")
           Y = m.addVar(lb=50,ub=59,vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="x")
           #m.addConstr (Y[0]==50)
    
           l=load[i]
           m.setObjective(((l-6*x)*(l-6*x)) , GRB.MINIMIZE)
           mip1.optimize()

Comment: @joni  please see my answer above. Unfortunately I couldn't import it properly. Can you guide me to a document or website? or see what might be wrong with the code? Tnx.

Comment: @saeed Edit your question and add your gurobi code there including the specific error message. At the moment it's hard to read and thus unlikely someone will help.

Comment: @joni Thanks for your time and help. I am pretty new to python and gurobi. But thanks to your encouragement, today I had good improvement and get good results. I am going to work on it more. If you have time, please check it and see if anything comes to your mind. (code is above) Tnx again.